# useCallback is recreate function when variable is not in dependency list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

Hello I have a Login modal where I also have function onSubmit, it's next js application. So it's changing state of setIsLoading, then it's recreating component, but not the function? Am I right?. There is another quastion below.

```
    const onSubmit : SubmitHandler<FieldValues> = (data)=>{
        setIsLoading(true);
        signIn('credentials',{
            ...data,
            redirect: false
        }).then((callback)=>{
            setIsLoading(false)

            if(callback?.ok){
                toast.success('Logged in')
                router.refresh()
                loginModal.onClose()
            }
            if(callback?.error){
                toast.error(callback.error)
            }
        })
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <Modal disabled={isLoading}
         isOpen={loginModal.isOpen} 
         body={bodyContent} title='Login'
          actionLabel='Continue' 
          onClose={loginModal.onClose} 
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          footer={footerContent}
          ></Modal>
    </div>
  )}
```

**Then I have Modal with function** that handles submit, and when I click multiple times on button, it's not sending multiple request, after first submit it's set disabled to true, but it's shouldn't because useCallback must use old values so it must be disabled == false. Help me, I can't figure out why it's happening. Also, why we use functions on useCallback, how it's suppose to change?

```
const handleSubmit = useCallback(()=>{
console.log(disabled)
if(disabled)
return
onSubmit()
}, [onSubmit])
```

I tried to google the question

Comment: Is the `disabled` prop on the `Modal` component what disables *some* button downstream? If you don't want the button disabled when the `isLoading` state is truthy then don't disable the button. It's not clear what your question is specifically about. Can you [edit] to clarify 1 specific issue or problem you have that you would like help with, and include a ***complete*** [mcve] of the relevant code *for that* issue/problem?

Comment: Hello. Disabled is prop on the Modal , and no, it's not disables the button. This is not a production application and a far-fetched example, I just want to understand why the handleSubmit function is being recreated, as for me, it should not change in any way. And why do you need to specify a function in the dependency array? When the function may change. Sorry, I'm new to react so question might be silly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. The `handleSubmit` function is created because you declared it. If it's being recreated it's because a dependency of the `useCallback` hook changes. Based on the code you have provided it would seem that `onSubmit` is a new reference each time the component renders and this would recreate the `handleSubmit` function. Well, maybe, I don't know... looks like you have at least a couple `handleSubmit` functions hanging around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useCallback` and `useMemo` are drastically overused and then you run into problems like this where you're not sure if you should leave things out of the dependency list and then you get stuck and confused about the whole thing.

The simplest solution is to just not use `useCallback/useMemo` (unless and until you are absolutely sure you need them, and you'll know when that is, trust me)

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
 if(!disabled) {
   return onSubmit()
 }
}
```